# Ckeditor - add textcolor, colorbutton in contextmenu

Tags: ckeditor, contextmenu, textcolor

is there anyway to add the colorbutton plugin to the contextmenu (right click) in ckeditor 4?

```
extraPlugins: 'autogrow,contextmenu,colorbutton',
```

```
editor.addMenuGroup('ck_group');
        

        editor.addMenuItem('bold', {
            label: 'Bold',
            command: 'bold',
            group: 'ck_group'
        });

        editor.addMenuItem('bulletedlist', {
            label: 'Elenco puntato',
            command: 'bulletedlist',
            group: 'ck_group'
        });

editor.contextMenu.addListener(function (element, selection, elementPath) {

                var contentMenuItems = {
                    //link: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON,
                    bold: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON,
                    italic: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON,
                    underline: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON,
                    numberedlist: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON,
                    bulletedlist: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON,
                    iconselector: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON,
                    formatting: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON
                };
```

i tried to add "colorbutton" as addmenuItem but did not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLkU3.png)

```
 editor.addMenuItem('TextColor', {
            label: 'TextColor',
            command: 'TextColor',
            group: 'ck_group'
        });

[..]

TextColor: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON,
```

did not work